# Angular 2 и внешний JS-скрипт

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Всем доброго времени суток! Делаю небольшое приложение на Angular 2, опыта немного. Возникла странная проблема - как подключить внешний скрипт и задействовать из него нужный функционал. Фрагмент app.component.ts.

```
import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import '../style/app.scss';
import 'lib/date-ru-RU.js';
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.getTypes();
  this.getOwnerships();

  this.pivots = 4;

  this.getAdms();
  this.getContainerTypes();

  // скорость
  this.speeds = [];
  this.speeds.push({label:'Грузовая', value:{id:1, name: 'Грузовая', code:    '1'}});
  this.speeds.push({label:'Большая', value:{id:2, name: 'Большая', code: '2'}});
  this.speeds.push({label:'Пассажирская', value:{id:3, name: 'Пассажирская', code: '3'}});

  this.date = new Date();
  **alert(this.date.format("dd.mm.yyyy"));**

}
```

Выдает ошибку в выделенной строке. Какой корректно подключить javascript-модуль к app.component.ts ? Спасибо.

Comment: что находится в _'lib/date-ru-RU.js'_?

Comment: дополнительные функции и свойства стандартного Date. Хочу получить дополнительное форматирование даты в конечном итоге.

Comment: вообще все должно и так работать